# Use Scopus API to retrieve abstracts of particular author?

Tags: python, api, scopus

I am relatively new to python. I am trying to use the scopus api to create a csv file that includes the text from all of the abstracts of a particular author. Any guidance on where to look for sample code would be much appreciated! I can't find documentation for how to use https://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus on python.

Answer (score 1):

There is a a Python module for use with api.elsevier.com, located here:

```
https://github.com/ElsevierDev/elsapy
```

Its aim is to make life easier for people who are not primarily programmers, but need to interact with publication and citation data from Elsevier products in a programmatic manner (e.g. academic researchers).

This is not an 'official' SDK and is not guaranteed to always work with Elsevier's APIs, on all platforms, or without eating up all your machine's resources. But we'll do our best to keep it in good shape, are happy to take suggestions for improvements, and are open to collaborations.

License info is [here](https://github.com/ElsevierDev/elsapy/blob/master/LICENSE.md):

Answer (score 1):

There's also the pybliometrics package that we develop - from the Scopus community for the Scopus community. In handles all the difficult parsing and accessing of the website, and also caches the responses for later use.

Here are examples accessing the Scopus Search API using the `ScopusSearch()` class of pybliometrics: https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/ScopusSearch.html

For your use case, you can simply do this:

import pandas as pd
from pybliometrics.scopus import ScopusSearch

```
q = "AU-ID(7004212771)"  # any query that works in the Advanced Search on scopus.com
s = ScopusSearch(q)
df = pd.DataFrame(s.results)
df.to_csv(OUTPUT_FILE)
```